# How to create a web service who calls a python web scraping script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, bottle

I am a python beginner and I need some help to create a web service that calls a python web scraping script (a task for a course).

I can use Bottle to create the web service. I wanted to use static_file to call the script but I am not sure about that because the documentation says that static_file is for CSS.

The idea is first to create the web service and later used the web scraping script from a server.

Thanks for your help and greetings from Colombia!

P.S. I don't have an excellent English but I hope someone can understand me and help me.

Comment: Why isn't your scrapping code in the bottle controller?

Comment: Hi Josep
Because i created the script before start to use Bottle. Do i need to repeat it (the Scrap script)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. unless it's already in a function, edit your scraping script so your code is contained within a function that returns whatever information you want. it should be as easy as indenting everything unindented and adding a `def main():`
2. let's say your script is called scraper.py and it's located along with your bottle controllers, at the top of your controller file add a `import scraper`.
3. in your callback you can call `scraper.main()`

(not sure why pasting the code here is not formatting it's below)

Having that said, it's usually bad practice to have something long running like a scraping script in a request. You'd usually want to use a queue of scraping jobs where your controller posts work to do, your scraper subscibes to it and notifies it when it's done caching the results somewhere.

```
from bottle import route, run
import scraper

@route('/scrape')
def scrape():
    return scraper.main()
```

Comment: Hi Josep
I understand the idea of import the "scrapper", but how can i calling from the web service created with Bottle? Using the bottle function static_files?
Thanks again i excuse me for my ignorance.

Comment: @DanielRomero I added a minimal code example; you may want to go over some basic Python tutorials.

Comment: fyi it's __scraper__ (and __scrape__, __scraped__, __scraping__) not scrapper

Answer (score 0):

you could try this guide I found:

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/

For the xpath stuff, I would suggest using Mozilla Firefox with the "Firebug" pluggin. It can generate xpaths for you which will help you write your script faster